# Difference between 2d string array and Array list of string

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im using

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Stringdata = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

to make a 2d array of string 
how is it different from using

```
String Stringdata[][] = new String[10][10];
```

Comment: An Array is different from an array list.

Comment: Java does not have two-dimensional arrays. A `String[][]` is actually an array of arrays of `String`s. --- Unlike arrays (which, when created, are fixed in size), lists are dynamic data strucutres: they can grow and shrink

Comment: I think your real question is... `How is an ArrayList different from an array?`

Comment: And if you google that, you will come up with infinite results

Comment: yes Thanks @RobOhRob that does take care of my question ! got a bit confused earlier

Comment: @Turing85 question wasnt updated and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ArrayList is a class that implements the interface List.
An array as per declared by:`String[] variable` is a finite-length data-structure in Java.

The main difference in using a 2D ArrayList instead of a normal array is that the length of an ArrayList is not limited. You may add as many elements to an ArrayList as your RAM allows.

On the other hand, `String[][] stringData = new String[10][10];` would limit this matrix to 100 elements (10 rows with 10 elements each). If trying to add an element to index 10 (notice the index only goes from 0 to 9) of a 10x10 matrix, the compiler would throw an error.

In general, if you already know how many spaces you will need in your matrix it is recommended that you use an array. Else, ArrayLists are really good.